# IOS5 AppCache not working

Tags: html, ios5, mobile-safari, offline-caching, html5-appcache

My site **[switchitoff.net](http://switchitoff.net)** has been happily using an appcache for a while now.  It works perfectly on all browsers that support appcache, including Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Mobile Safari... except that it fails on **IOS5**.

On **IOS4** I could browse to my site, add it to my homepage and relaunch the site from its new shortcut.  At this stage the site would be cached, so that I could run it offline from the shortcut.  If I try the same thing in **IOS5** I get:

> ***Cannot Open Switch It Off***
>
> *Switch It Off could not be opened because it is not connected to the Internet.*

The Mobile Safari debug console shows no errors, and I'm not sure how I can debug this any further.  I don't know if this is a clue but the appcache status constantly comes back as `updateready`.  I assumed it must be an **IOS5** bug, but no-one else is moaning about it so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

By the way before you jump on your iPhone and test it, the site is designed for iPad and desktop browsers (OK, laptop browsers too).  It won't work well on an iPhone, although you can still try running it offline from a homepage shortcut and see it you get my error.

Cheers

Comment: OK, so no response on this one.  So can I instead ask if anyone has got AppCache to work with IOS5?

Comment: I'm getting two "JavaScript: Error \n undefined \n JavaScript execution exceeded timeout" errors on the debug console (iPad 2, iOS5).  You may also want to handle Private browsing.

Comment: This doesn't help answer the question, but I can confirm that the issue exists even across emulators. My app uses a UIWebView and the AppCache and it's broken in iOS5